# How can I add a GUI to a pre-existing C++ console application?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I have a simple C++ console application and wondered if there would be any way to add a GUI without having to remake the application.

I am using a MinGW compiler, the Eclipse CDT IDE and standard and boost libraries.

Answer (score 0):

(without knowing much of the console application)

You will have to remake the application.

If the console application is "well made", user interaction disconnected from actual functional code, then it should be a straightforward conversion.

Just create the appropriate UI and call the necessary functions.

For example if your console application contained a textual menu and asked answers, then you will have buttons and/or menu and/or edit box in the GUI that you will need to patch up to the code.

Max.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite the application you could trying using a separated engine and interface pattern where the GUI and console apps are separate executables where the GUI spawn an instance of the console app and communicates with it to drive the application through some mechanism, e.g. Stdin

If your console application cannot be driven this way you nay need to change / rewrite the app

Answer (score 0):

You should detail your question in order to get more precise answers.

What is the level of interactivity your console application provide ?

**- It's just like a simple command with input parameters that produce output at end of the program**

in this case, you can just code a gui front end that will get the parameters from a form or whatever you need and then your gui application will launch the console command, parse the result and display it in the gui.

**- the console application is very interactive (takes input from the user during all the execution)**

- the console application code very big and very coupled to console interaction :

Maybe you can write a gui wrapper that takes std::in and std::out and render the two streams in gui widgets but that can be tricky. This is not a very pleasant solution, it should be used only if you really don't want to get inside the console application code.

- the console application code is not that big or its easy to split the console input/ouput part from the rest of the program :

In this case, you should make a library from your app and then write a gui for it.